# How to verify application up or not?

Tags: linux, unix, shell-scripting

I would like to write a script to check whethere the application is up or not using unix shell scripts.

From googling I found a script `wget -O /dev/null -q http://mysite.com`, But not sure how this works. Can someone please explain. It will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wget` is an HTTP client, so you're making a web request to http://mysite.com.  You'll have to check the exit status of the `wget` command: if the request is successful, the exit status will be "0", and otherwise if it's not successful.

So, your check script may look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -O /dev/null -q http://mysite.com

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
  echo "Web site is down!"
fi
```

If you're not really sure about shell scripting, it might be better to use a service that will perform the check, along the lines of Pingdom.

Update:

Instead of using `wget`, it may be better to use `curl`.  Something like this:

`curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" http://mysite.com -o /dev/null`

This will return the HTTP response code, so you can do more obvious controlled comparisons (i.e., curl will return 404, whereas wget will return some non-zero exit code that you have to figure out from documentation)

Comment: Thanks a lot cjc !!!, One more doubt how long it will wait for the response before exit? any idea??

Comment: wget's timeout is by default 900 seconds.  You can change this to something else with the `--timeout=seconds` option.  What you should set this for depends on your website, how long you think a reasonable response to take, etc.  Look at `man wget` for all the options.